How to get the width of the macOS dock?
I want/need to place a dock-alike window in the "empty" areas left or right of the macOS 14+ system dock, when located at the bottom.
Getting the height of the dock is easy, e.g. as shown here: How to get Position, Width and Height of Mac OS X Dock? Cocoa/Carbon/C++/Qt
But getting the actual width or dimensions of the dock, and thereby the uncovered space left and right of the dock, seems to be impossible.
Does anyone have any ideas or hints where to look, other than brute force, taking a screenshot and analyzing it?
I followed any hint I can find, tried everything I can find. But it seems there is no API that supports (directly or indirectly) to retrieve the size, both height AND width, of the Dock.

Have you tried the Accessibility API?

I would implore you to think critically about the UX requirements to which you're alluding here - it's highly likely that bolting on a Dock-like thing to the Dock itself would cause significant user confusion when said bolt-on doesn't look and/or behave the same way the Dock itself does.

In more recent MacOS versions it seems that the Accessibility API has become more restrictive and more focussed on supporting an individual application. Methods like mentioned in the following post do not seem to work anymore: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684278/getting-the-position-of-my-applications-dock-icon-using-cocoas-accessibility-a

You can hack a solution together using calls to AppleScript per below; be forewarned that this does require your application to be whitelisted as an accessibility application in System Preferences before this will work.
Assuming the Dock is centered (see note 1 below), you would need to take the int value returned by this method and subtract it from the full width of the screen itself; the result of that calculation, then halved, should correspond to the amount of space on either side of the Dock on screen.
- (int) getDockWidth {
    // Define AppleScript source code to execute
    NSString *appleScriptSource = @""
    "tell application \"System Events\" to tell application process \"Dock\" to set dockSize to the size of list 1\r"
    "return dockSize";
    
    // Create landing zone for the error dictionary that NSAppleScript can dump error information to
    NSDictionary *errorDict = NULL;
    NSAppleScript *appleScript = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:appleScriptSource];
    NSAppleEventDescriptor *eventDescriptor = [appleScript executeAndReturnError:&errorDict];
    if (errorDict != NULL) {
        [NSException exceptionWithName:@"Error executing AppleScript" reason:nil userInfo:errorDict];
    }
    return [[eventDescriptor descriptorAtIndex:1] int32Value];
}

A couple of notes:

This approach does not consider when the Dock has been pinned in a specific position on the screen differing from the centered default.
In its current form, this method also does not currently support a scenario where a user has moved the Dock to reside anywhere else other than the bottom of the screen (i.e., left or right) although it would be trivial to detect with the addition of a few more lines of code.
There is likely a better, more native way to do this through the Accessibility API & without involving AppleScript. I'm just not personally aware of how that would look in practice.


That's quite hacky, but it instantly worked. Thank you very much. But asking for accessibility permissions is a big question to ask, so I likely make this intended window positioning rather an optional feature.

I will continue to search for alternatives and add them to this thread.
